# Emulating Square behavior with Stripe or Braintree

Tags: email, stripe-payments, braintree, pci-compliance

I recently paid for an item at a farmers market using the merchant's Square card swipe. Upon swiping, Square offer to send me an email receipt, as it had already associated my email address to that credit card.

What suggestions would you have on how one might emulate this behavior using Stripe or Braintree in a PCI compliant way?

It would be great to configure a kiosk so that when a customer buys an item, we receive back their email address if on file. If not on file, we can gather this information and pass it back to the processor. The next time the user returns to the kiosk, they are presented with option to receive an email; or they can opt out of the receipt or update their email.

Any insight appreciated.

Comment: If the service doesn't support it, there's nothing you can do, except for keeping your own customers on file.  You can't make the processor do it for you.

Comment: Swiping cards like that is ~usually it's own type of compliance.  You could check out Stripe's supported POS systems (some of them may function that way).  https://stripe.com/works-with/categories/card-readers-pos